# How to generate the a1 opcode for mov eax,moffs32

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, nasm, mov

As an aid to understanding the x86 instruction set, I've been trying out various forms of `mov` in NASM and comparing the generated code with the opcodes listed in the Intel documentation. Most of them come out as I expected, but there's one I can't seem to get NASM to generate:

```
a1    mov eax,moffs32
```

In particular, this doesn't do it (assembles to a different opcode instead):

```
mov eax,[44332211h]
```

Same goes for the 64-bit variant and the inverse opcode a3. How do you get the assembler to generate these opcodes? Am I misunderstanding what 'memory offset' means?

Comment: My `nasm` (version 2.10.01) assembles your example to `A1`. You didn't say what the alternate was, it could have been the more generic `8B /r mov r32, r/m32` but that's one byte longer and shouldn't really be preferred by the assembler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NASM is probably picking a shorter variant. In 64-bit addressing mode the A1 opcode has a 64-bit address making the instruction 9 bytes long: `A1 11 22 33 44 00 00 00 00`. By picking an opcode with an ModR/M encoding it lets use a 32-bit offset instead resulting a 7 byte long instruction. Eg: `8B 04 25 11 22 33 44`

Comment: You're right, I retried in 32-bit mode and it used A1 presumably because it was not now longer than the alternative. That does lead to another question though: in 64-bit mode, `mov rax, [8877665544332211h]` gets a complaint that the offset is still supposed to be only 32 bits. Is NASM getting that wrong?

Comment: Yah, it looks like NASM is getting it wrong. That instruction assembles correctly for me under MASM and GAS: `48 a1 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88`

Comment: Regarding the `mov rax, [8877665544332211h]` comment: if you want NASM to pick the `mov rax, moffs64` encoding you can do that by adding a `qword` specifier, as in `mov rax, [qword 8877665544332211h]`.